# How to make Quicksort code stable without libraries? (Java)

Tags: java

I am currently trying to make a Quicksort in java. The only problem is that I just can't make it stable (so that the order of reccurring elements is still the same). My code so far:

**Update:** Thank you for all your answers but sadly I 'm not allowed to use any libraries like java.util for LinkedLists etc.

```
public void quickSortStable(Integer[] data) {
    int IndexZero = 0;
    int IndexLength = data.length-1;

    sortQuicksortArray(data, IndexZero, IndexLength);
}

public int createQuicksortPartition(Integer[] data, int IndexZero, int IndexLength){
    int pivot = data[IndexLength];
    int i = (IndexZero-1);
    for (int j=IndexZero; j<IndexLength; j++)
    {
        if (data[j] < pivot)
        {
            i++;
            int temp = data[i];
            data[i] = data[j];
            data[j] = temp;
        }
    }
    int temp = data[i+1];
    data[i+1] = data[IndexLength];
    data[IndexLength] = temp;

    return i+1;
}

public void sortQuicksortArray(Integer[] data, int IndexZero, int IndexLength){
    if (IndexZero < IndexLength)
    {
        int partition = createQuicksortPartition(data, IndexZero, IndexLength);

        sortQuicksortArray(data, IndexZero, partition-1);
        sortQuicksortArray(data, partition+1, IndexLength);
    }
}
```

Comment: So, a common optimization people use with quick sort is to bail out of recursion when the gap is small (usually around 7 or so). If you add that optimization, and pick a stable sort (like insertion sort) you get something else for free. See [also](https://yourbasic.org/golang/quicksort-optimizations/#combining-algorithms).

Comment: Thanks, but I'm not allowed to use anything else. I have to make the stable version of Quicksort using only quicksort "logic".

Comment: Variable and parameter names should begin in lowercase so they don't get confused with class names which starts in uppercase.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The quicksort algorithm is not stable by nature.

There are already some [good answers](https://www.quora.com/Why-is-quick-sort-not-a-stable-sorting-algorithm) on quora.

In short, each partition is not stable, because quick sort may swap the outer elements before the middle elements.

for example,

```
// original
4(a) 4(b) 3 2(a) 2(b)
^                 ^
// after first partition 
2(b) 4(b) 3 2(a) 4(a)
      ^      ^
// after second partition
2(b) 2(a) 3 4(b) 4(a)
```

Since the partition is not stable, the overall algorithm cannot be stable.

Answer (score 0):

You can make the quicksort sorting stable when you save the elements which are smaller or bigger than the pivot in two temporary lists (or one array) and add them back to the original input array when you have separated the values. The pseudo algorithm looks like this:

```
public int createQuicksortPartition(Integer[] data, int startIndex, int endIndex){
    List<Integer> lower = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    List<Integer> higher = new ArrayList<Integer>();

    Integer pivot = data[endIndex];

    for (int i=startIndex; i<endIndex; i++) {
        if (data[i] < pivot) {
            lower.add(data[i]);
        } else {
            higher.add(data[i]);
    }

    // readd them to the input array
    for (int i=0; i<lower.size(); i++) {
        data[startIndex+i] = lower.get(i);
    }
    data[startIndex+lower.size()] = pivot;
    for (int i=0; i<higher.size(); i++) {
        data[startIndex+lower.size()+i] = higher.get(i);
    }
    return startIndex+lower.size();
}
```

*(untested pseudo code)*

This obviously need `O(n)` additional space to have a copy of the data to sort. You also have to take extra care for the pivot element and the "higher" elements, which are equal to that pivot. These have to added **before** the pivot element to ensure that the sorting is stable, because the pivot element was the last element from the input array. In this case the ordering should be:

1. Elements smaller than the pivot
2. Elements equal the pivot
3. The pivot itself
4. Elements greater than the pivot

You can solve this by using three lists for smaller, equal and greater values and add them back to the input array accordingly.